# In a Karate Scenario Outline test, I aim to construct the Examples using query results retrieved from the Cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, karate

I'm using a Cassandra database and attempting to implement API test automation using KARATE. I aim to generate test data from the database, process it in JavaScript to build the POST request's body as JSON for the Examples in the Scenario Outline.

After installing Cassandra driver in my Karate codebase, I encountered an issue with sending a request body in a Scenario Outline. However, upon removing the request body from the scenario, it started functioning correctly

[image: Trying to check is Scenario Outline examples works]

[image: After adding request body, getting error]

[image: It is working when, removing request body]

Comment: sorry you seem to be new to stack overflow, read this and try to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I got solution for this to changing package. 
com.datastax.oss's cassandra is working as well. com.datastax.cassandra is getting error.

Comment: glad you got it working!